# Nested mixins in LESS throws an error

Tags: nested, arguments, less, mixins, parse-error

I'm trying to have a `.flexbox` mixin that accepts an argument `@orient`, which should automatically apply `box-orient` as well. When using it in combination with `!important`, I'm experiencing an error that is also reproducible with a more narrowed-down testcase:

```
.foo() {
  .bar;
}

.bar {
  color: red;
}

body {
  .foo() !important;
}
```

This makes LESS throw an error (I'm using it in node.js):

```
C:\...\node_modules\less\lib\less\parser.js:385
                        throw new(LessError)(e, env);
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined
```

Oddly enough, using `.foo` instead of `.foo()` works as expected:

```
.foo {
  .bar;
}

.bar {
  color: red;
}

body {
  .foo !important;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried your code with less 1.3.0 [online](http://www.dopefly.com/less-converter/less-converter.html) and it's working fine. Maybe it's some node problem or some issue with an old lesscss version?

Comment: @kapep: Woops, thanks for checking. I had narrowed it down too much. I'm actually using it in combination with `!important`. The online version throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search led me to this bugreport. It is a known issue.

https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/740

To be honest I would suggest you try to accomplish what you're trying to do some other way. The less.js backlog is at time of this writing 417 issues large. It isn't likely going to be fixed any time soon.

(yes it is this bugreport, you created a nested rule by extending .foo with .bar)

Comment: Hmm yes, that seems to be the same thing. I'll leave it for now then. Thanks.